# VideoJS unable to set playback rate when using custom audio context

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, html5-audio, video.js

The only way I am aware of  boosting audio past 100% with the Video JS library is to setup a slightly janky custom audio context with a gain node.
**This makes changing the playback rate not work.** I understand that `player.tech()` is not really intended to be used but it seems like this is the only way to boost audio volume.

Is there something I am doing wrong here? If so what is the best way be able to both boost volume past 100 as well as control playback rate?

```js
const normal = videojs('normal', { "playbackRates": [1, 4] });
    const boosted = videojs('boosted', { "playbackRates": [1, 4], enableSourceset: true });
    boosted.on("sourceset", () => {
      const context = new window.AudioContext();
      const gain = context.createGain();
      context.createMediaElementSource(boosted.tech().el()).connect(gain);
      gain.connect(context.destination);
      gain.gain.value = 10;
    });
```

With VideoJS:

https://codepen.io/qhyun2/pen/gOgPKqP

Without:

https://codepen.io/qhyun2/pen/abpZmMB

## Solved!

This is a [bug in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1517199)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `resume()` the `AudioContext` from within a click handler. The following should work.

```
const context = new window.AudioContext();
const boosted = videojs(
    'boosted',
    {
        enableSourceset: true,
        playbackRates: [1, 4]
    }
);

boosted.on("play", () => context.resume());
boosted.on("sourceset", () => {
    const gain = context.createGain();

    context.createMediaElementSource(boosted.tech().el())
        .connect(gain)
        .connect(context.destination);

    gain.gain.value = 10;
});
```

However it doesn't work on codepen.io. The video file isn't served with the necessary CORS headers.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This isn't working for me however. I should I been more clear, my issue is not with the video not playing but with the set playback rate being ignored. When I run the video audio through the gain node, playback rates that I set are ignored and the video still plays at the default speed. I think this might be a fundamental limitation of the API. Here is a simpler example without video-js: https://codepen.io/qhyun2/pen/abpZmMB.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that. There seems to be [a bug in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1517199) which makes it ignore the playbackRate. It works in Chrome. It also works in Safari but the video is very choppy when you change the playbackRate in Safari.